# how can I export mysql database using ssh?

Tags: mysql, ssh

What commands I can use at ssh to export(download) mysql database using SSH?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To **export a mysql dump using SSH**, execute the following command:

```
mysqldump -u username -p dbname > db_dump.sql

username -> your mysql username
dbname   -> your database name
```

Enter password when prompted. And you are done.

Have a look here: [**MySQL Import and Export (.sql file) via SSH**](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/112)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it worked but now the file is at root directory how can I move it to another folder?

Comment: ssh by default creats the dump on root folder so if u want to move that to another directory you would may need to specify path before the dump file or write an other script to move that file to another directory.

Comment: @user1026722 Please mark this answer as correct if it helped you out.

Answer (score 5):

I guess its too late but for a detail answer for future reference:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p yourdbname > /var/dbbackup/backup.sql
```

here you can change the username root to yours -p will ask for your password later. and after the > you can mention your location where you want to save your backup file.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump db  | ssh test.host mysql db
```